# How to register last access to a page

Tags: php, session-variables

I have a website that needs to register the last access from an user to some pages. Eg:

```
MoviesPage.php
Terror
    Subpage1
    Subpage2
    Subpage3
Action
    Subpage1
    Subpage2
    Subpage3
Adventure
    Subpage1
    Subpage2
    Subpage3
Comedy
    Subpage1
    Subpage2
    Subpage3
Crime
    Subpage1
    Subpage2
    Subpage3
... etc
```

I need to register the last access to each genre and to each subsection, so when some new content is uploaded, I know if a specific user has seen it or not.

For example,`User 1` clicked `'Comedy -> subpage1' link` at `2015-05-11 9:30:00` , and if some new content is uploaded after this date I need to show a 'New content' icon.

Actually I have implemented this feature using sessions, but I have noticed that this is a very bad solution .

What is the best way to register this access information?

Comment: Nice, I had not thought about it. Thank you XNeyte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies should be the answer to your question.

You can check How it works on w3schools here : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

You have to know that it will work only for users who has enabled javascript and allows cookies. Some users are blocking cookies. You should consider to add an informative text saying to users that your website is using cookies.

Comment: Thank you xNeyte. I'm changing the session implementation to your solution.